# Mostrar datos por usuario en php

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar

Realicé un calendario en el que muestra las citas de asesores y vendedores, el problema que tengo es que solo se deben mostrar el del asesor (que inicio sesion) con el campo `j_id` y los asesores que tiene a su cargo campo `user_id`, he intentado con este código pero no muestra nada.

```php
$resultado_eventos = "WHERE ( user_id = '"
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['user_id'])
            . "' OR j_id = '"
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['user_id']) . "' ) ";
if ( $resultado_eventos === false) {
    die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

```html
<?php   
    $active9="active";
    $requerido = ['LIDER'];
    require_once 'seguridad.php';
    $title ="CALENDARIO DE CITAS | ";
    
    include "head.php"; 
    include "header.php"; 
    include "aside.php"; 
    
    

include_once("db.php");

$consulta_eventos = 
"SELECT 
id, 
u_fullname, 
color, 
nombre_cliente, 
telefono, 
nss, 
curp,  
created_at, 
time_created, 
updated_at, 
inmobiliaria2_direccion, 
inmobiliaria3_zona, 
credito_name, 
estatus_name, 
u_fullname, 
j_fullname   


FROM v_cita_completo 
";


       

?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <h1>Dashboard<small>Panel de control</small> </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
    </ol>
  </section>
  <div class="x_title">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="big-box bg-write">
        <!-- small box -->
        <center><img class="image view view-first" style="width: 40%; display: block;" src="images/logos/logo.png" alt="image"></center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <link href='css/personalizado.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0px 0px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script src='locale/es-es.js'></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          defaultDate: Date(),
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          eventClick: function(event) {

            $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
            $('#visualizar #title').text(event.u_fullname);
            $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $('#visualizar #nombre_cliente').text(event.nombre_cliente);
            $('#visualizar #telefono').text(event.telefono);
            $('#visualizar #nss').text(event.nss);
            $('#visualizar #curp').text(event.curp);
            $('#visualizar #time_created').text(event.time_created);
            $('#visualizar #inmobiliaria2_direccion').text(event.inmobiliaria2_direccion);
            $('#visualizar #inmobiliaria3_zona').text(event.inmobiliaria3_zona);
            $('#visualizar #credito_name ').text(event.credito_name);
            $('#visualizar #estatus_name ').text(event.estatus_name);
            $('#visualizar #u_fullname ').text(event.u_fullname);
            $('#visualizar #j_fullname ').text(event.j_fullname);
            $('#visualizar').modal('show');
            return false;

          },

          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          select: function(start, end) {
            $('#cadastrar #start').val(moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $('#cadastrar #end').val(moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $('#cadastrar').modal('show');
          },
          events: [
            <?php
                            while($registros_eventos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_eventos)){
                                ?> {
              id: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              id ']; ?>',
              title: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              u_fullname ']; ?>',
              start: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              created_at ']; ?>',
              time_created: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              time_created ']; ?>',
              end: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              updated_at ']; ?>',
              color: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              color ']; ?>',
              nombre_cliente: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              nombre_cliente ']; ?>',
              telefono: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              telefono ']; ?>',
              nss: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              nss ']; ?>',
              curp: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              curp ']; ?>',
              inmobiliaria2_direccion: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              inmobiliaria2_direccion ']; ?>',
              inmobiliaria3_zona: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              inmobiliaria3_zona ']; ?>',
              credito_name: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              credito_name ']; ?>',
              estatus_name: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              estatus_name ']; ?>',
              u_fullname: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              u_fullname ']; ?>',
              j_fullname: '<?php echo $registros_eventos['
              j_fullname ']; ?>'



            },
            <?php
                            
                            }
                        ?>
          ]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#FDFEFE">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!--fecha_inicial elementos contenedor-->






            <div class="page-header">
              <center>
                <h1>Calendario | Citas</h1>
              </center>
            </div>
            <br />

            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])){
                echo $_SESSION['mensaje'];
                unset($_SESSION['mensaje']);
            }
            ?>

              <div id='calendar'></div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal fade" id="visualizar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background:#3c8dbc; color:white">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Datos de la Cita</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <dl class="dl-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong><center><mark>DATOS CITA</mark></center></strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <br />

                    <dt>ID CITA:</dt>
                    <dd id="id"></dd>

                    <dt>FECHA:</dt>
                    <dd id="start"></dd>

                    <dt>HORA:</dt>
                    <dd id="time_created"></dd>

                    <dt>ESTATUS CITA:</dt>
                    <dd id="estatus_name"></dd>
                    <br />

                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong><center><mark>DATOS DEL CLIENTE</mark></center></strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <br />

                    <dt>NOMBRE CLIENTE:</dt>
                    <dd id="nombre_cliente"></dd>

                    <dt>TELÉFONO:</dt>
                    <dd id="telefono"></dd>

                    <dt>NSS:</dt>
                    <dd id="nss"></dd>

                    <dt>CURP:</dt>
                    <dd id="curp"></dd>


                    <dt>CRÉDITO:</dt>
                    <dd id="credito_name"></dd>
                    <br />

                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong><center><mark>DATOS INMUEBLE</mark></center></strong></h4>
                    </div>


                    <dt>DIRECCIÓN</dt>
                    <dd id="inmobiliaria2_direccion"></dd>

                    <dt>ZONA</dt>
                    <dd id="inmobiliaria3_zona"></dd>
                    <br />


                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong><center><mark>DATOS ASESOR</mark></center></strong></h4>
                    </div>


                    <dt>ASESOR:</dt>
                    <dd id="u_fullname"></dd>

                    <dt>JEFE / LIDER:</dt>
                    <dd id="j_fullname"></dd>
                  </dl>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>





</div>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Debería solo mostrar las citas del usuario logueado y asesores a su cargo, pero muestra una vita general.
[image]

Comment: ¿Has depurado tus variables? ¿Con qué resultados?

Comment: Qué tiene que ver esto con java? Utilicemos bien las etiquetas, por favor...

Comment: No se como esperas que `$resultado_eventos` te de algo (ni false ni nada). Tal como lo has puesto no haces nada más que asignarle una cadena de texto que empieza por WHERE, etc.  Supongo que debes concatenar esa cadena con la primera parte que falta (la del supuesto SELECT entiendo yo).  Lo más raro de todo es que te muestre todos cuando no deberia mostrarte nada tal como está ahora.

Comment: @masterguru, efectivamente si le coloco el "código" donde intento que solo me muestro los datos que requiero no muestra nada, en el código que coloque no tiene ese $resultado_eventos entonces ahí si me muestra lo que adjunto en la imagen pero muestra todas las citas generadas en la tabla sin importar quien las creo

Comment: @Carlos En la pregunta empiezas esa variable donde vas a guardar la consulta  `$resultado_eventos` con el texto `WHERE`.  Si eso es una consulta tipo SELECT debe empezar por `SELECT loquesea FROM dondesea` y luego el resto que has puesto ahora con el `WHERE`.   No se si me explico. Y una cosa más, luego lo usas como si fuera una consulta **ejecutada** en el `mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_eventos)` cuando no lo es para nada, es simplemente un string. Debes aun ejecutarlo con otra variable y luego arreglar ese  `mysqli_fetch_array` conforme a ello